# why do i get view not found after publishing .net core application

Tags: linux, docker, .net-core, dockerfile

I am building docker image and running a container from it. this container is running a .net core 2.0 web application. however after running it i get the error diplayed in the image below.

I have added this to my Program.cs already

```
.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
```

[image]

Comment: did you update your docker image with new changes ?

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. It doesn't work in docker, but it does when I just run it on linux. Did you solve it?

Comment: @Turowicz .net core version might be your issue, see the changes i made in the answer bellow

Comment: @Turowicz let me know if that helps.

Comment: @ifelabolz I can't remember what I did but I believe it was the .NET version indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Old way**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseApplicationInsights()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

**New Way**

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();
}
```